# Validate TM Forum Open-APIs against Apache 2.0 standards

Tags: swagger, openapi

We are moving from RAND to Apache 2.0 licencing for TM Forum Open-APIs (http://tmforum.org/open-api). Is there an automatic way to validate them against Apache 2.0 standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are developing a Python application that allows you to validate TMForum Swagger files to the expected Apache 2.0 and TMF standards, you can check it [here](https://github.com/EricFernandezDC/TMFValidator). If you have any question on how it works please let me know!

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer. Please follow the guidelines.